# How to get access to the HTTP Rest API end points of network parameters in corda community edition?

Tags: corda

I am trying to check the HTTP network map protocol in the sample cordapp example, I have used network bootstrapper to generate node info files. But I need to check the Rest API end points mentioned in the docs: /network-map/publish.

Is it necessary to set up the network map for this? If required,I am not able to get the corda-network map jar file for the community edition. How to access those API endpoints ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cordapp samples available in the samples repository uses a locally bootstrapped network. The network bootstrapper is used for this purpose to generate the node-info and the certificates of the network participants. It's a quick and easy way to set up a static Corda network for the purpose of local deployment and testing.

It doesn't have a network map service. The node-info files of each participant is dropped into the additional-node-info folder of the nodes which serves as the network map cache for the node.

The REST end-points you mentioned are available in a real network map service running as part of a dynamic Corda network setup (mostly) used for production deployments.

R3 does not provide a community version of the network map.

However, there is a commercial offering called CENM (https://docs.corda.net/docs/cenm/1.2.html). It's not just a Network Map but also takes care of other aspects of Network Management like Identity and Signing.

In case you are looking for an open-source network map you could try out Cordite Network Map (https://marketplace.r3.com/solutions/cordite-network-map) developed by one of our partners.

Comment: Got it @ashutosh meher . I tried using cordite network map,tried to set up a nms service in the docker,but instead had some serializationEnviornment issue . I have tried in windows as well as linux platform

Comment: We have a channel #cordite on the Corda public slack (http://slack.corda.net/). The cordite devs might be able to help you there.